# calculating Z-values for path over surface described by x-values, y-values, and z-matrix in R

Tags: r

The x axis and y axis is described by Longitude and latitude range values (1d-vectors),
The z axis is described by a 2d matrix.

How I can estimate the z value for a give lon/lat position in the surface?

```
    terra= interp(x, y, z, xo = lons[i], yo = lats[i]))
```

is not working as expected (akima) due to the case, that z has another dimension:

> Error in interp(x, y, z, xo = lons[i], yo = lats[i]) :
> Lengths of x, y, and z do not match

The size of the matrix z is x * y.

Comment: If you are using `interp` from the package `akima` (or the package `interp`), the x, y and z values all need to be the same length, so you need something like `interp(rep(x, each = length(y)), rep(y, length(x)), as.vector(z))`

Comment: Is there any alternative to the akima interp for this application?

Comment: Yes -see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line here is that `akima::interp` is probably the wrong tool for what you are trying to do, and you should instead use:

```r
pracma::interp2(x, y, z, xp = lat[i], yp = lon[i])
```

---

**Explanation**

If I am understanding you correctly, you have a matrix `z` that represents a 3D surface. The latitude of each row is stored in the vector `y` and the longitude of each column in the vector `x`. You wish to find out the implied value of z for any arbitrary x, y co-ordinates that are not on the original grid using 2D interpolation.

This isn't really what the function `interp` is for (see below for an explanation of what `interp` does). It would be better here to use a function that specifically interpolates a 2D matrix such as `pracma::interp2`.

For example, suppose I have the following x, y, z objects, similar to your own set up:

```r
x <- seq(0, 45, length = 10)
y <- seq(-45, 45, length = 10)
z <- outer(x, y, function(x, y) x^2 + y^2)

x
#>  [1]  0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
y
#>  [1] -45 -35 -25 -15  -5   5  15  25  35  45
z
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,] 2025 1225  625  225   25   25  225  625 1225  2025
#>  [2,] 2050 1250  650  250   50   50  250  650 1250  2050
#>  [3,] 2125 1325  725  325  125  125  325  725 1325  2125
#>  [4,] 2250 1450  850  450  250  250  450  850 1450  2250
#>  [5,] 2425 1625 1025  625  425  425  625 1025 1625  2425
#>  [6,] 2650 1850 1250  850  650  650  850 1250 1850  2650
#>  [7,] 2925 2125 1525 1125  925  925 1125 1525 2125  2925
#>  [8,] 3250 2450 1850 1450 1250 1250 1450 1850 2450  3250
#>  [9,] 3625 2825 2225 1825 1625 1625 1825 2225 2825  3625
#> [10,] 4050 3250 2650 2250 2050 2050 2250 2650 3250  4050
```

We can see this draws a concave surface:

```r
persp(x, y, z, theta = 225, phi = 30, col = 'gold')
```

[image]

Now suppose I have some lat, lon co-ordinates that are within this domain but not directly on the original grid:

```r
lat <- c(12.3, 4.6, 5.1)
lon <- c(-5.3, 0, 4.1)
```

I can work out the z value at these three points like this:

```r
pracma::interp2(x, y, z, xp = lat, yp = lon)
#> [1]  835.75 1801.50 1817.75
```

Which seems to be the type of output you are looking for.

---

---

**Why not akima::interp here?**

By contrast, `akima::interp` tries to create a regular matrix of x, y, z values representing a 3D surface, given only a few x, y, z co-ordinates on that surface. It therefore creates a regular grid *when you don't already have one*, rather than interpolating arbitrary points between an existing regular grid.

We can show this by turning our x, y and z objects into a set of points and feeding them to `interp`. if we expand the x and y vectors and turn z from a matrix to a vector, we create 3 vectors of length 100 that represent the x co-ordinates, y co-ordinates and z co-ordinates of points on our surface. Feeding these to `akima::interp` will result in a smooth 40 x 40 grid being created from the original data:

```r
persp(interp::interp(rep(x, length(y)), rep(y, each = length(x)), z),
      theta = 225, phi = 30, col = 'gold')
```

[image]

Since you already have a regular grid, this does not seem to be what you need.